# How do I load my CSS file using Node with a switch statement

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, backend

I'm having an issue with loading my CSS file once I start my node server, I'm not quite sure why this issue is occurring, when I use a live server locally the CSS runs correctly but when I run it from the server that I built, everything but my CSS is loaded. here is my backend code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Status for the file is 200;
response header is undefined;
and the requesting url is `/public/CSS/style.css`

```
 const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const { extname } = require('path');
const app = express();
const figlet = require('figlet');
const { connect } = require('tls');
const exp = require('constants');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000

app.use(cors());


let server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    // Creates File Path
    let filePath = path.join(
        __dirname,
        'public',
        req.url === '/' ? 'index.html' : req.url
    );

    console.log(filePath)


    // Gets Extension from a file
    let extname = path.extname(filePath);

    console.log(extname)

    // Default Content Type
    let contentType = 'text/html';



    switch (extname) {

        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
            break;

        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;

        case '.json':
            contentType = 'application/json';
            break;

        case '.jpeg':
            contentType = 'image/jpeg';
            break;

        case '.jpg':
            contentType = 'image/jpg';
            break;

        case '.png':
            contentType = 'image/png';
            break;

        case '.webp':
            contentType = 'image/webp';
            break;
    }

    // Read File

    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {

        // If ENONENT Error is returned
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                figlet('Page Not Found!!', (error, data) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log('Something went wrong');
                        console.dir(error)
                        return
                    }
                    res.end(data, 'utf8')
                })
            }
            else {
                // Some Other Error
                console.log(err.code)
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end(`Server Error: ${err.code}`);
            }
        } else {
            // Success
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            res.end(content, 'utf8');
        }
    });

});


server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`The Server is running on port: ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: Please post the request URL and the response status and headers of the problematic CSS request.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen The request url is /public/CSS/style.css and the status code is 200

Comment: header: host: 'localhost:8000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
  accept: 'text/css,*/*;q=0.1',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'style',
  referer: 'http://localhost:8000/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'}

Comment: @HeikoTheißen    Do you need anything else?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen would this be a boolean value ?

Comment: when logging res.getHeader('content-type') I get undefined.

Comment: Seems that the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">` element in your HTML page has a wrong `href`, because the stylesheet URL (`/public/CSS/style.css`) should _not_ contain the `/public` segment. This is already added by the `path.join` statement on the server, so the server looks for the stylesheet at `/public/public/CSS/style.css`.